# Get all visible CKEditor instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, ruby-on-rails-5

It is possible to loop through all the CKEditor instances like:

```
for(var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances) {
  ...
}
```

Some of the CKEditors are hidden in my case. So, how is it possible to loop through the visible CKEditors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up checking the visibility of the closest `div`

```
for(var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances) { 
  if($("#"+instanceName).closest(".form-group").is(':visible')){
     ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with setTimeout(function(){},1000); 
as sometime one javascript instance is ongoing and by loop it is going to create another one so may b chances for nonworking.
try your logic with setTimeout .it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances) { 
setTimeout(function(){ 
  if($("#"+instanceName).closest(".form-group").is(':visible')){
     ...## your code goes here
  }
}, 3000);
}
```

Try like this way...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (var instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {        
    if (CKEDITOR.instances.hasOwnProperty(instance)) {             
        if (CKEDITOR.instances[instance].closest(".wrapper").is(':visible')) {
            ...
        }         
    }
}
```